# Laravel, best practices: first fill form, then login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an application with Laravel 5.2 for classifieds ads, a classified belongs to a user, the flow should be like this:

A homepage with a 'Post Classified' link

After the (unauthenticated) user fills the create-classified form, which includes file uploads, he gets prompted to login.

Following best practices, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

- Should I save the classified in the database with a user_id of, let's say -1 until the user logs in, then update the record? what happens if the user never logs in?
- Should I keep the classified in a session, then save it after the user logs in? What happens with the file uploads?

Note: Code not necessary, just an explanation of what would be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not save the data in DB initially as I do know know the user yet and usually user is is the primary key. Intermediate table does not sound good wither.

I would save the data in session, store files on HDD and keep the file location also in session. Once registration is over then enter the data to the DB. We also need to keep in mind that the there might be need for cleanup of the files of users that never register. However I do not think it will be a big problem.